# Как в Ubuntu перейти в нужную директорию через терминал?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я знаю, что в терминале с помощью команды `cd` можно перемещаться по папкам, но я вставил флешку, и она у меня показывается на уровне `Devices`, как показано  на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот слева на этом скрине над строкой `Computer` есть строка `U3` - это и есть моя флешка, но когда я открываю терминал и пишу `cd U3` или `cd Devices` то мне показывает, что нет такой команды...

Как открыть флешку через терминал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

посмотрите примонтированные файловые системы, например, с помощью программы *df*. те, что монтировались позже, занимают более низкую строчку. пример:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdb        15418648 3172000  12246648  21% /media/usb0
```

в последнем столбце указана точка монтирования. в приведённом примере это каталог `/media/usb0` (в вашем случае, вероятно, будет что-то типа `/media/пользователь/U3`).

вот его и надо указывать параметром для встроенной команды оболочки *cd*:

```
$ cd /media/usb0
```

---

как подсказывает @serxcio в комментариях, иногда в выводе программы *df* может отсутствовать инфорамация о примонтированной с отключаемого носителя файловой системе. в этом случае имеет смысл воспользоваться программой *mount*. последние примонтированные файловые системы также будут ближе к концу вывода. пример:

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sdb1 on /media/usb0 type iso9660 (ro)
```

Comment: Ввел df, потом подключил к ноуту телефон и опять ввел df и ничего не поменялось... Ноут как будто не видит, что к нему что то подключилось... Хотя на телефоне я включил режим debug и Android Studio его видит... В случае с плеером это помогло, а вот телефон не видит... Что то делаю не так?

Comment: цитата из `man df`: *df - report file system disk space usage*. т.е., отображается информация о примонтированных файловых системах, а не о подключенном оборудовании.

Comment: Я наверное не до конца понимаю определение... Значит если я подключаю флешку или плеер то это примонтированное  оборудование, а если телефон то это подключенное оборудование... верно? Ок, тогда может вы знаете как я могу попасть в файловую систему подключенного оборудования? У меня все выглядит так как на скриншоте в вопросе только вместо U3 у меня Samsung... какая команда мне может помочь?

Comment: *Значит если я подключаю флешку или плеер то это примонтированное оборудование, а если телефон то это подключенное оборудование... верно?* — нет, конечно. по поводу остальных вопросов: задавайте их, пожалуйста, в виде вопросов, а не комментариев.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Телефоны, фотоаппараты иногда подключаются через fusefs, и тогда их `df` не показывает в общем списке.

Comment: @sercxjo, это какая-то особая реализация fuse? я на практике не встречал случаев отстутствия в выводе df (от имени примонтировавшего пользователя) информации о примонтированных средствами fuse файловых системах.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin gvfs. mount их показывает независимо от подключения устройств, а df  только если директорию явно указать.

Comment: @sercxjo, спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от используемой оболочки и версии системы, но в Ubuntu 15.04 стандартный файловый менеджер nautilus в контекстном меню директории (по правой кнопке мыши) имеет пункт "Открыть в терминале". В открывшемся окне терминала введите команду `pwd` и узнаете настоящий путь к данной директории, например для смартфона:

```
$ pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C004%5D/Внутренняя память
```

Для более ранних систем 14.04 и 12.04 требуется установить пакет nautilus-open-terminal
(https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu/250909)

Comment: В 14.04 такого нет((

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko дополнил ответ

Comment: О, кстати прикольная штука. Но все равно не открывает в терминале путь к файлам телефона(( Все открывает, но когда в телефоне, то терминал появляется и сразу же исчезает...

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /media/<user>/<your USB stick>
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуй `cd /media/твояфлешка/`

Comment: раньше было так