# Как открыть телефон в Ubuntu? если таким способом не получается cd /media/user/device

Tags: ubuntu

Есть похожий вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497625/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-ubuntu-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB/497629), но мне не подходит такое решение так как когда я ввожу команду df телефон не распознается...

Дериктория называется `Samsung` и расположение ее видно на скриншоте, какой путь нужно прописать после команды `cd` чтоб попасть туда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вводить по разному(перечислил внизу)

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ cd "/media/aleksey/SAMSUNG Android"
bash: cd: /media/aleksey/SAMSUNG Android: No such file or directory
aleksey@aleksey:~$ cd /media/aleksey/SAMSUNG\Android
bash: cd: /media/aleksey/SAMSUNGAndroid: No such file or directory
aleksey@aleksey:~$ cd /media/aleksey/SAMSUNG\ Android
bash: cd: /media/aleksey/SAMSUNG Android: No such file or directory
aleksey@aleksey:~$
```

Путь показывается таким образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Ubuntu перейти в нужную директорию через терминал?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497625/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-ubuntu-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb)

Comment: В целом мне подошла команда sudo nautilus, у меня открылся наутилус под рутом и я смог сделать все что хотел

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите в данном окне комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> и вверху появится путь до данного каталога.

Comment: Да действительно путь к каталогу появился, но я не уверен, что он верный... Прикрепил скришот к вопросу

Comment: Посмотрите возможные ответы здесь http://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Проверил, у меня монтируется в следующую директорию:

```
/run/user/12345/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C054%5D$
```

Здесь 12345 - id пользователя, у вас будет другой, но в целом там негде заблудиться. Делайте так и смотрите, какой у вас:

```
id --user
```

после gvfs идёт как раз тот текст, который показывается в качестве пути при нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. В моем случае это был `mtp://[usb:001,054]/`.

Ответ на основе https://askubuntu.com/q/342319/455773

Comment: Ок, я не до конца понимаю где вы берете путь "host=%5Busb%3A001%2C054%5D$" , я так понял это порт который при каждом подключении может менять свое значение. Я перешел по ссылке и проследовал инструкции. Выполнил первую команду которая была указана "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp" и потом обновился "sudo apt-get update" , потом я ввожу "$lsusb" для проверки подключений, но я так и не понял как понять, что нужно указать после "host=% (и набор цифр)". Как узнать это?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko углубляйтесь постепенно, на каждом шаге смотрите, из чего дальше можно выбрать.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko чтобы смотреть, используйте `ls` или gui

Comment: Так а куда углубляться? я ввожу `/run/user/1000/gvfs` у меня открывается директория... я ввожу `ls` там пусто я ввожу ls -a чтоб посмотреть скрытые файлы и у меня показывает, что и скрытых файлов там нет... Команда gui у меня не работает, пишет, что не знает что это за команда... так а в вашем случае как вы нашли то, что написано после `/run/user/12345/gvfs/` ? так как в эту директорию я попал и мне осталось ввести только хвост `mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C054%5D$` но где его взять?